# Removing duplicates in Text Box and adding the corresponding values

Tags: vb.net, addition

I have a VB form with three TextBoxes. Here's an example of what I'd like the program to achieve:

So, that's the form ... the program sorts a text file and gets names, goals, and positions. E.g.

- Jordan    26    Center
- James    10    Mid
- Jordan    4    Center
- Jack      6     Forward
- James 10 Mid

When the update button is clicked, the program should realize that James and Jordan are written twice, remove one of them and add their goals, so it should output:

- Jordan    30    Center
- James    20    Mid
- Jack      6     Forward

To do this I've had the data transferred into ListBoxes which makes it easier to remove duplicates, the data is then transferred back into a multi-line TextBox so it is editable. Here's my code so far. It either gives the wrong results or an index out of range error.

```
Dim Count1 As Integer
Dim Count2 As Integer
Dim Count3 As Integer
Dim NewInt As Integer
Dim ValOne As Integer
Dim ValTwo As Integer
ListBox1.Items.Clear()
ListBox2.Items.Clear()
ListBox3.Items.Clear()
NewInt = 0
ValOne = 0
ValTwo = 0
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(Players.Text.Split(vbNewLine))
ListBox2.Items.AddRange(Goals.Text.Split(vbNewLine))
ListBox3.Items.AddRange(Positions.Text.Split(vbNewLine))
Count1 = ListBox1.Items.Count
Count2 = ListBox2.Items.Count
Count3 = ListBox3.Items.Count
If Count1 = Count2 And Count1 = Count3 And Count2 = Count3 Then
    'Set two counters to compare all words with each other
    For iFirstCounter As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        For iSecondCounter As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
            'Make sure there will not be an 'out of range' error,
            'because you are removing items from the listbox.
            iSecondCounter = Convert.ToInt64(iSecondCounter)
            iFirstCounter = Convert.ToInt64(iFirstCounter)
            ListBox2.Items.RemoveAt(iSecondCounter)
            ListBox2.Items.RemoveAt(iFirstCounter)
            If iFirstCounter < iSecondCounter Then
                ListBox2.Items.Insert(iFirstCounter, NewInt.ToString)
            Else
                ListBox2.Items.Insert(iSecondCounter, NewInt.ToString)
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Players.Text = ""
    Goals.Text = ""
    Positions.Text = ""
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        If Players.Text = "" Then
            Players.Text = ListBox1.Items(i)
        Else
            Players.Text = Players.Text & vbNewLine & ListBox1.Items(i)
        End If

    Next
    Dim a As Integer
    For a = 0 To ListBox2.Items.Count - 1
        If Goals.Text = "" Then
            Goals.Text = ListBox2.Items(a)
        Else
            Goals.Text = Goals.Text & vbNewLine & ListBox2.Items(a)
        End If
    Next
    Dim b As Integer
    For b = 0 To ListBox3.Items.Count - 1
        If Positions.Text = "" Then
            Positions.Text = ListBox3.Items(b)
        Else
            Positions.Text = Positions.Text & vbNewLine & ListBox3.Items(b)
        End If
    Next
Else
    MessageBox.Show("The Text Boxes don't contain an equal number of values ... please add more/remove some values")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be done in multiple ways, for example:

```
 If TextBox2.Lines.Count > 1 Then
        Dim LineList As List(Of String) = TextBox2.Lines.ToList 'textbox lines
        Dim NewLines As List(Of String) = TextBox2.Lines.ToList 'can't edit list we're looping over, a copy of lines

        Dim NamesList As New List(Of String)
        For x = 0 To LineList.Count - 1
            Dim linesplit As String() = LineList(x).Split({" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            If NamesList.Contains(linesplit(0)) Then
                NewLines.Remove(LineList(x))
            Else
                NamesList.Add(linesplit(0))
            End If
        Next
        TextBox2.Lines = NewLines.ToArray
    End If
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response that's sorta what I want to do but I want the output to be Jordan 30 Center ...  James 20 Mid ... like I understand how to remove the duplicate lines but I'm having trouble getting it to add up

Comment: I simply took the text from your textbox and removed "duplicates". As you said in your OP. If you want a proper answer you should edit your question to contains : "I have">"this happens">"I want this instead"

Comment: If you want to use listbox, you can adapt the code and do the same. Loop over "names" remove duplicates by index (in all listboxes at once).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of code that does this via LINQ and Lambdas.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()



        Dim ungroupedPlayers(1) As String
        ungroupedPlayers(0) = "Jordan 26 Center"
        ungroupedPlayers(1) = "Jordan 4 Center"

        Dim players = ungroupedPlayers.ToList().ConvertAll(Of Player)(Function(x As String) As Player
                                                                          Dim split() As String = x.Split(" "c)
                                                                          Dim p As New Player
                                                                          p.PlayerName = split(0)
                                                                          p.Count = split(1)
                                                                          p.Position = split(2)
                                                                          Return p
                                                                      End Function)
        Dim playersGrouped = From p In players
                             Group By PlayerName = p.PlayerName Into g = Group
                             Select PlayerName, Count = g.Sum(Function(ip As Player) ip.Count), Position = g.Min(Function(ip As Player) ip.Position.ToString())

        Dim groupedPlayers() As String = playersGrouped.ToList().ConvertAll(Of String)(Function(ip)
                                                                                           Return ip.PlayerName.ToString() & " " & ip.Count.ToString() & " " & ip.Position.ToString()
                                                                                       End Function).ToArray()
         For Each groupedPlayer as String in groupedPlayers
             Console.WriteLine(groupedPlayer)
         Next
         Console.Read()
    End Sub

    Public Class Player
        Public PlayerName As String
        Public Count As Integer
        Public Position As String
    End Class

End Module
```

Comment: Hi, sorry are you able to explain your code like where would I put it? I tried running it in a new form and doing console.writeline() then the variables in it but the variables were coming up empty. Also is your code able to add up the corresponding values? Thanks

Comment: It's not writing to the console at the moment...do u need that added?

Comment: @Jordant123 added a write statement...this is where you would put your UI code to add to the listbox instead

Answer (score 0):

You don't need heavy `ListBox` control for working with players data.
Use `List(Of T)`  and create class `Player` for better readability.

You can remove duplicates before you will display values in your form.
And instead of multiline textbox you can use `DataGridView` as "right tool for the editing data".

```
Public Class Player
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Position As String
    Public Property Goals As Integer
End

Public Class PlayersForm : Form
    Private Sub Form_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim data As List(Of Player) = LoadPlayersData()
        Dim players As List(Of Player) = NormalizeData(data)

        ' Use DataGridView
        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = players                                                
    End Sub

    Private Function LoadPlayersData() As List(Of Player)
        Dim rawData As String() = File.ReadAllLines("pathToTextFile")
        Return rawData.Select(Function(line) LineToPlayer(line)).ToList()
    End Function

    Private Function NormalizeData(players As List(Of Player)) As List(Of Player)
        Return players.Group(Function(player) player.Name)
                      .Select(Function(group)
                                  Return New Player With
                                  {
                                      .Name = group.Key,
                                      .Position = group.First().Position,
                                      .Goals = group.Sum(Function(player) player.Goals)
                                  }
                              End Function)
                      .ToList()
    End Function

    Private Function LineToPlayer(line As String) As Player
        Dim values = line.Split(" "c)
        Return New Player With
        {
            .Name = values(0),
            .Position = values(2),
            .Goals = Integer.Parse(values(1))
        }
    End Function
End Class
```

`DataGridView` control will automatically update your List(Of Players) when you make any change. which give you possibility to have some other controls which automatically display best scorers for example, without extra converting data from string to integer and back.

Comment: Hey, that's actually a really good idea thanks! I'm just not sure where to put your code in because i'm getting errors like DataGridView1 is not a member of Form3.Player or group is not a member of list of form3 player or file is not declared yeah so I tried to put your code inside the form load section but there's still errors. Thanks, Jordan